# Python, FASTAPI and PlanetScale - I cannot connect to the my MySQL Database because of some strange SSL error

Tags: python, mysql, docker, fastapi

I'm hosting FASTAPI app inside of a docker container. I can build and run docker and run the application perfectly fine in the browser. The issue occurs when I call an API that attempts to talk to my MySQL db from the hosting platform PlanetScale. Provided are my dockerfile:

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM python:3.6.4
#WORKDIR /etc/ssl/
#add /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs:ro
RUN mkdir /apis
#RUN mkdir /etc
#RUN mkdir /etc/ssl
WORKDIR /apis
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY main.py .
COPY prod.env .
COPY cert.pem /etc/ssl/
RUN  python -m pip install --upgrade pip
#RUN  pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN  pip install "fastapi[all]"
RUN  pip install mysql
RUN  pip install mysqlclient
RUN  pip install python-dotenv
RUN  pip install PyMySQL
COPY . .
#CMD yum update ca-certificates
# THE BELOW SECTION IS POPULATED WITH THE CORRECT SETTINGS.
ENV HOST=<>
ENV USERNAME=<>
ENV PASSWORD=<>
ENV DATABASE=<>

RUN echo "Host: $HOST"
RUN echo "Username: $USERNAME"
RUN echo "Password: $PASSWORD"
RUN echo "Database: $DATABASE"
#RUN cd /etc/ssl/
#COPY /etc/ssl/ .
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=80"]
```

When I attempting to run an api I get the following error:
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: unknown error number')

Any ideas

Comment: It might be useful to try to get this working without Docker first. This will give you confidence that the right libraries are being installed in the right order.

Comment: This didn't workout side of docker either.

Comment: Then it’s nothing to do with Docker. Same error?